# Foreign Key constraints on Inherited attributes in sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

I am defining an inherited class called  `Type1Edge` which connects to nodes, I want to make sure that the two nodes are in the same system as to not connect to unrelated nodes. Therefore I want to check that both of the nodes appear with the same sys_id in the nodes table. I want to perform the check on the inheriting class `Type1Edge`. If I define `sys_id` only in `BasicEdgeObject` I can't check forigen key constraint
`ArgumentError: Column(s) 'fss_id' are not part of table 'type_1_edge.` 
and if I put `sys_id` on both I get a warning
`SAWarning: Implicitly combining column basic_edge_object.fss_id with column qualification.fss_id under attribute 'fss_id'.`
Is there a standard way of doing this?.

```
class BasicEdgeObject(Base):

__tablename__ = 'basic_edge_object'
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
sys_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('sys.id'))

__mapper_args__ = {
    'polymorphic_identity': 'basic_edge_object',
    'polymorphic_on': obj_type
}

__mapper_args__ = {
    'polymorphic_identity': 'basic_node_object',
    'polymorphic_on': obj_type
}
class Type1Edge(BasicEdgeObject):

__tablename__ = 'type_1_edge'
id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('basic_edge_object.id'), primary_key=True)
node_1_id = Column(Integer)
node1= relationship('Node', back_populates='edges', foreign_keys=[node1_id])
node2_id= Column(Integer)
node2= relationship('Node', back_populates='edges',foreign_keys[node2_id])
name = Column(String)

__table_args__ = (ForeignKeyConstraint([node1_id,sys_id],                                         
                  [BasicNodeObject.id,BasicNodeObject.sys_id]),
                  ForeignKeyConstraint([node2_id, sys_id], 
                  [BasicNodeObject.id, BasicNodeObject.sys_id]))

__mapper_args__ = {
    'polymorphic_identity': 'qualification',
}`
```

Comment: `sys_id` and `node1_id` are part of different tables; you can't define a composite foreign key with columns from different tables. You can either use single table inheritance instead, or just duplicate the definition of `sys_id` on all child tables (and don't define it on `basic_edge_object`).

Comment: Thanks @univerio , I probably should have shown the node table too but it also contains  `sys_id` as foreign key. I am trying to make sure here that the edge is connecting nodes on the same system(graph) by checking that both nodes appear on  the nodes table with the same `sys_id` as the edge object

Comment: I understand exactly what you are trying to do, but what you're trying to do is not possible with the schema that you have right now. You'll need to change your schema in one of the two ways I've suggested.